# Select 1 query using Hibernate Criteria

Tags: java, hibernate

I need the following query to be converted into Criteria API.

Native Query:

```
Select 1 from Table
```

May i know how to convert this into criteria query?
What I tried so far:

```
Criteria criteria = session.createCriteria(MyEntity.class); 
criteria.add(Restrictions.eq("id",getId())); 
criteria.add(Restrictions.eq("Code",getCode()));
criteria.setFirstResult(0); 
criteria.setMaxResults(1);

if (criteria.uniqueResult() != null) 
      return true; 

else return false;
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? You might want to read [HowToAsk](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) first

Comment: I have tried using : 
Criteria criteria=session.createCriteria(MyEntity.class);
  criteria.add(Restrictions.eq("id",getId()));
  criteria.add(Restrictions.eq("Code",getCode()));
  criteria.setFirstResult(0);
  criteria.setMaxResults(1);
  if (criteria.uniqueResult()!=null)
   return true;
  else
   return false;

Comment: And what was the problem you encountered?

Comment: since the above query is returning an entire object and it is impacting performance . So i would like to return 1 when the value is present in db.

Comment: hi, what about doing a select count?

Comment: The above query is used to check whether the record exists or not in the database. Usage of count is not preferred here.

Comment: One option can be Projections.sqlProjection("1",new String[]{"1"},new Type[]{ShortType.INSTANCE})